# Low Battery problems

Tags: ipod-touch

I have and iPod touch 4th Gen. I got it when it was first out and it is 8GB. However whenever I use it, the Battery goes down to less than 20% in the First hour. This makes me very annoyed. How do I fix it?

Comment: The 4th generation iPod touch was produced in 2010. Dependent on usage it's possible that the battery has lost its capacity. This is more or less normal battery behaviour. You can get the battery replaced, or if you've premium quality DIY skills you can replace it [yourself](http://www.ifixit.com/Guide/iPod+Touch+4th+Generation+Battery+Replacement/9829/2)

Comment: @BartArondson Sounds reasonable, just add it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 4th generation iPod touch was produced in 2010. Dependent on usage it's possible that the battery has lost its capacity. This is more or less normal battery behaviour.

You can get the battery replaced, or if you have premium quality DIY skills you can replace it [yourself](http://www.ifixit.com/Guide/iPod+Touch+4th+Generation+Battery+Replacement/9829/1).

Comment: Thanks that helps a lot. I thought I did something wrong. Also where can I get anew batteries and who replaces them?

Comment: New batteries can be found through Google and people who replace them as well. Your choice of repairshop depends on your location, so I can not find look it up four you.